# How do I debug separate code blocks in RStudio?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, workflow, breakpoints

R kernel requires the file to be 'sourced' before any breakpoints can be activated - meaning you have to effectively execute the whole script in the console first. This only is acceptable if your scripts are either divided in short and well separated chunks and standalone functions, like a bag of tools. But what if your script consists of raw lines of code which are not working well together, and some even not working or bugged?
Is there a better solution than switching to Jupyter Notebook to benefit from its 'cells'?

Comment: If your code is organised that way, why do you need a breakpoint as opposed to just stepping through the code until the "breakpoint"?

Comment: @AllanCameron because there are functions too; because I sometimes need reusable blocks of code

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio, you can run any number of lines of code ([LINK](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code-in-the-RStudio-IDE#:%7E:text=Executing%20Multiple%20Lines)) and view the output in the environment.

If you're debugging, you can also use functions such as browser(), debug(), and debugonce().

Comment: but i want to use breakpoints and a full-fledged debugger with a call stack and watches